# Reputation shown is less than what it really is

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation

Today I received a 15 reputation for the answer accepted by the OP, but for whatever reason when I check it in the app I realised that this wasn't updated.

**Profile view from app:**

[image: profile not updated on app]

But when I checked the same on my achievements section, I saw that there is a recent update today which has given me 15 reputation for an accepted answer.

**Achievements tab from app:**

[image: achievement is updated]

Other strange thing I noticed is that, this behaviour is not only in the Android app, but in SO as well irrespective of the device it was accessed from (desktop or mobile).

**Stack Overflow site from mobile view:**

[image: SO mobile browser]

I'm not sure if this is how Stack Exchange is designed or this is a bug which requires serious attention as it doesn't portray real-time data on Exchange site (issue with website is still ok).

**My device config:**

- OS Type: Android
- OS version : 4.4.4
- App version : 1.0.73

Comment: Caching. Give it a couple of hours.

Comment: @Yannis not always. Sometimes things get stuck for weeks in there, I recall quite a few bug reports of the "My Communities" reputation out of synch.

Comment: if your saying caching issue,then I would totally disagree with it. how different is the functionality of updating the reputation on profile banner vs the reputation appearing at the individual communities. also on the stackexchange app if your saying it would take couple of hours, then i would say its a bug for sure for not being  a real-time app

Comment: @ShadowWizard That might be the case, but we won't know it's stuck and not caching unless we give it a couple of hours.

Comment: @dreamweiver Who said this is supposed to be updated in real time? I wouldn't expect (near) real time updates for something so inconsequential.

Comment: @Yannis: i would totally dis-agree with your statement, if it was so insignificant then why was there different reputation value at different places. also what's the point of having an app being online  always and not being  real-time. to me this is a bug & I wouldn't be convinced unless i get realistic answer than just assumptions

Comment: Given that it also happened on mobile browser, this is not a bug of Android app. Possibly caching, or server hiccup, but only SE devs can answer that.

Comment: Hope to see some response from the devs soon

Comment: Sounds like caching to me. IIRC the network-level tables that power the community list (and probably the app? not too sure there) can be updated on a delay.

Comment: @AdamLear: well I feel its beyond caching issue, because the reputation data shown against the communities is not in sync with the current community reputation(refer 3rd image) shown at top of the SO site.

Comment: @dreamweiver The data comes from the same spot... sort of. Individual sites maintain their own records (and they're the source of truth). But anything network-wide (such as the "your communities" part of the site switcher) comes from tables that aggregate that info from site-specific databases. So, I agree that it should be more in sync *in general*, but out of curiosity, how long does it take for your rep to update?

Comment: @AdamLear: I dont have a accurate data on that, but i remember it synchronised properly when i checked it the next day. on the other hand, i was able to reproduce this issue even now, so i tried resetting the cache once for SO domain and you know what you were right, this was a caching issue.http://superuser.com/questions/278948/clear-cache-for-specific-domain-name-in-chrome . **So i would suggest SO dev team to set a lesser expiration period for cache, so that the sync will happen at the earliest**